# HTML, JS - after clicking the button: wait 5 seconds, add css class, run link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, hyperlink

I want to have a button which after clicking will add css class to other div, wait 5 seconds and then run link.

Instead of `$(this).animate` I would like to have `addclass` but it doesn't work

```js
$(function() {

  $('div').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var goTo = this.getAttribute("href");

    // ACTION END
    $(this).animate({
      marginLeft: 300
    }, 3000);
    // ACTION START

    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location = goTo;
    }, 3000);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='btn1' href="slider.html">
  <div id="btn1-in">Go Stack!</div>
  <div id="btn1-in2">Go Stack!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What your problem exactly?

Comment: `$(this).addClass('aClassName')`?

Comment: instead "$(this).animate({marginLeft:300},3000);" I would like to have addClass but it doesn't work

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: I wanted to add class not to clicked div but for example the div it contains

Comment: @WiktorPółtorak In the sample you've provided, the clicked div contains only a text node. If you want to add a class to a child node, then use `$(this).find(".btn-child-1").addClass("btn-child-2")`. It adds `btn-child-2` class to a child that already has `btn-child-1` class so that it has both classes in the end.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of $(this).animate I would like to have addclass but it doesn't work

try this:

```
setTimeout(function() 
{$(this).addClass("AddNewClass") },5000);
```